# How to force rebase when same changes applied to both branches manually?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, reset, rebase

My repository looks like:

```
X - Y- A - B - C - D - E             branch:master
     \                  \
      \                  \ merge master -> release
       \                  \
        M  ---  BCDE  ---  N         branch:release
```

Here "M - BCDE - N" are manually (unfortunately!) applied changes approximately same as separate commits "A - B - C - D - E" (but seems GIT does not know that these changes are the same). I'd like to rebase and get the following structure:

```
X - Y- A - B - C - D - E     branch:master
                        \
                         *   branch:release
```

I.e. I want to make branch:release to be exactly the same as branch:master and fork it from the master's HEAD.

But when I run "git rebase master" sitting at the branch release, GIT reports about lots of conflicts and refuces rebasing. How could I solve this?

Other explaination of this: I'd like to "re-create" branch:release from scratch from master's HEAD. And there are a lot of other people who had already made "git pull" for the branch:release, so I cannot use git reset + git push -f.

Comment: You're not really asking the right question here - you've established that you can't rewrite history with `push -f`, so you absolutely cannot rebase. What you want is a way to *merge* and discard changes (which is what I provide in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You say that people have pulled the release branch already, so you can't reset. That also means you can't rebase - either way, you move the ref in a non-merge way, and upset everyone else.

Assuming that you want to throw away *everything* on the release branch (I'm a little confused by the `M`) and make it identical to master (why do you show the `*`?), here's what you can do:

```
git checkout master
git merge --strategy=ours release   # merge in release, but keep master's contents
git checkout release
git merge master                    # fast-forward
```

You'll end up with this:

```
X - Y- A - B - C - D - E ----- Z (master, release)
     \                  \     /
      \                  \   /
       \                  \ /
        M  ---  BCDE  ---  N
```

The merge commit `Z` will have discarded all changes from release; it's just there to ensure that release moves in a fast-forward. From the documentation:

> ours
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.

This is exactly your situation!

It's also not a bad idea to use the `--no-commit` option on the merge, then commit manually so that you get a chance to edit the message and note what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git rebase -i master` and remove the line for `BCDE` to discard that revision altogether. If it really is identical to `A-B-C-D-E`, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Though the OP asked about rebase, it's not actually an option, because people have already pulled the branch.